# How to report a bug to a GitHub project, that is missing an issues page?

Tags: github

I wanted to try out this project for recording audio files to Android, [libogg-vorbis-android](https://github.com/nwertzberger/libogg-vorbis-android).

Unfortunately, it looks like the project is missing some files that weren't added and committed to the repository (I get errors like "Project 'libogg-vorbis' is missing required source folder: 'unit'", container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library libogg-vorbis.jar)

I would report a bug/question on the issues for this project, but there isn't any issues page on this particular project. Why are issues hidden on this project, and is there a way to report something elsewhere?

Comment: Did you try looking at the author and running down his blog? Took 3 clicks to get to http://www.ideaheap.com/about-ideaheap/

Answer (score 1):

Issues are an optional feature on GitHub repos. Some project maintainers just choose to not open that part and instead would rather you create a pull request, which is standard and activated on all repositories.

To track down a way to contact the owner/maintainer(s) of the project:

- Look at the profile of the user or organisation under which the project falls under. They will often have either an email or website you can contact them through
- See if the repo has a project page, where they may list contact details
- The README will often include contact information